# Try to understand Vue2's $emit

Tags: vue.js

I wonder how Vue2's $emit works?

On its API(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit), it says:

> Trigger an event on the **current** instance. Any additional arguments
> will be passed into the listener’s callback function.

If current instance means the component defined, while its main usage is to send signal to parent(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events)

I wonder how to understand this(the way how the event passed is pretty confused to me)?

Comment: the parent is just the definition, like `<foo> </foo>` while the child is the actual source code for that component, so the emit is sent from child to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `$emit` register an event in a component, and then you can listen to this event in other places wherever the component is used.

Say if you have a `Child.vue` and somewhere in this component, you did:

```
.$emit('some-event')
```

Then you can listen to this event when `Child` component is reused, for instance in another component `SomeComponent.vue`, you can do:

```
<template>
    <child @some-event="doSomething"></child>
</template>
```

So here the event is triggered in the child component, but you decide what to do in the parent component with `doSomething`. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

The wording on the docs might create confusion to some people.

Maybe something in the lines of: "Makes the `vm` current instance dispatch an event" would be clearer?

In the end it is just a classic pub/sub pattern: your component instance emits / dispatches / fires an event, and other components (typically the parent one) listen / subscribe (`v-on` / `@`) to that event.